# Highest refractive index dielectric

Tags: material-science, refraction, dielectric, electrical-engineering, optical-materials

What is the material or metamaterial that is a very good dielectric and has a very high refractive index at least in frequencies below $500\ MHz$?

Answer (score 0):

Single crystal CCTO has a reported $\epsilon=10^5$.
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6625108/
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6223690/

A very stable dielectric is HfO2:
"The advantage for transistors is its high dielectric constant: the dielectric constant of HfO2 is 4–6 times higher than that of SiO2."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafnium_dioxide

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please tell me where can i find the refractive index value that you said?

Comment: The paper is have you is of 2019 so it should be up to date. On Wikipedia you will find a top level overview of dielectrics, and you should use $\epsilon = n^2$. I am sure there is more behind pay walls and in patents.

Comment: I corrected the typo.